# chef-jira cookbook - Cookbook apache2 not found

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, chef-infra, jira, cookbook

I have downloaded the cookbook "chef-jira" and now I am trying to run it using chef-solo/vagrant on Ubuntu 12.04.

After a lot of googling and stackoverflow support i was able to get the json file picked up which defines the run lists. But the below error has been troubling me and I am totally clueless.

```
==> default: [2014-08-20T03:33:41+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook apache2 not found. If you're loading apache2 from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
==> default: [2014-08-20T03:33:41+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

If anyone can look at the cookbook and suggest me some solution I will be grateful.  The url of the cookbook is: https://github.com/bflad/chef-jira

Comment: paste your vagrantfile.. Each cookbook can has dependencies.. It has 'apache2', 'ark', 'database', 'java', 'mysql', 'mysql_connector', 'postgresql'. Have you satisfy it?

Comment: Using the vagrantfile from the cookbook itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The README links to all the cookbooks that it depends on. You can either download these manually and add them to your cookbooks folder, use `knife cookbook site install` to download them for you, or investigate the Berkshelf cookbook manager which downloads dependencies automatically. The simplest way to get started is probably to install the vagrant-berkshelf plugin and next to your Vagrantfile create a Berksfile containing just

```
metadata
```

The next time you run `vagrant provision` it will download all the dependencies for you.